# CKEditor режет все теги и скрипты yii2

Tags: yii2

CKEditor режет все теги и скрипты yii2.

vendor/mihaildev/yii2-ckeditor/editor/config.js
вписала

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
config.height = 50;
config.indentClasses = '["article-contents__items"]';
config.protectedSource.push(/<(style)[^>]*>.*<\/style>/ig);
config.protectedSource.push(/<(script)[^>]*>.*<\/script>/ig);// разрешить теги <script>
config.protectedSource.push(/<\?[\s\S]*?\?>/g);// разрешить php-код
config.protectedSource.push(/<!—dev—>[\s\S]*<!—\/dev—>/g);
config.allowedContent = true; /* all tags */
```

}

не помогает

Answer (score 0):

Подключите нормальный редактор и будет вам счастье
[Ckeditor](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget)

Comment: так он и есть Ckeditor

Comment: да, но тот что я вас скинул, будет работать так как надо